# Pattern to force consuming of queue

Tags: java, design-patterns

Currently I have a method to consume events of a Queue. Based on the type I call the appropriate method to handle it.

```java
private void consumeQueue() {
    MyQueue myQueue = MyQueue.getInstance();
    Iterator mIterator = myQueue.iterator();
    while (mIterator.hasNext()) {

        Object mEvent = null;
        try {
            mEvent = mIterator.next();
            mIterator.remove();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return;
        }

        if (mEvent instanceof EventOne)
            handleOne((EventOne) mEvent);
        else if (mEvent instanceof EventTwo)
            handleTwo((EventTwo) mEvent);
        ...
    }
}
```

Let's suppose that elsewhere the developer enqueue a new type of event, let's call it EventThree. Doing it in this way I can't be sure that the developer will handle EventThree's consumption properly.

Is there any pattern so I can force (at compile time) the developer, to handle EventThree's consumption?

Comment: The better way would be to force each `Event` to have a `handle` method.

Comment: Simple polymorphism (`mEvent.handle()`), or the visitor pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: By this you mean I'd need to force the developer to extend Event base class, which is implementing an interface with handle() inside? But then, how do I force him extending Event?

Comment: Well, by making sure that methods that add events to the queue take Event instances as argument, and not Object instances.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to accept your answer, if you add it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your `MyQueue` class implements `Queue` interfance. You should never use [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) in your code. Consider using your `MyQueue` as a generic class with some type parameter:

```
MyQueue<EventOne> myQueue = MyQueue.getInstance();
```

Ofc you'll have to change `getInstance()` method too. An elegant solution may look like:

```
<T> MyQueue<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == EventOne.class) {
        // ...
    } else if (clazz == EventTwo.class) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

P.S. Unfortunately you can't define two `getInstance()` methods with different `Queue` type parameter because of Java's [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: This is true, even if not related to the question, thank you.